# Unable to load arm64-v8a .so on arm64 device

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have built an application targeting only *arm64-v8a* devices. I have built the respective .so files and placed them under *arm64-v8a* folder under *libs*. 
Now when I try to install the application on devices like nexus 6p, nexus 5x, samsung s6, one plus three(which are of arm64-v8a architecture), I am getting error `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` though the abi's are available.

Now if I include armeabi-v7a libs as well, the application is working fine. It is picking *armeabi-v7a* libs on *arm64* device despite having those libs.
The .so file is built against AArch64 which supports arm64-v8a architecture.

Same is the case with x86_64 as well.

I have placed the apk and application code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7eQ8JMBWlsMZ2F2RUNuaVA3WFE. 
We are not sure if this is some thing wrong with the way we built the application or it is an issue with ndk.

Attached the emulator configuration as well [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YWTd.png)

Comment: Have you ever figured out why they don't load? I'm having the same issue. In logcat all I get is "W/NativeHelper: Failure copying native libraries [errorCode=-113]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue got solved when I changed the renderscriptTargetApi to 21. Previously it was 19, due to which it was loading 32 bit binaries.